# Odd GridView Column size

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview and I am trying to increase size of a column in it when user clicks on **Edit link button** using this code,

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // Comments
        TextBox comments = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[column_index].Controls[control_index];
        comments.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        comments.Height = 100;
        comments.Width = 400;
    }
}
```

**Problem**

It works but only works for Odd Gridview rows, and rest even number of rows stays same, can anyone direct me to solution please ?

Comment: can you be bit clear and elaborate ?

Comment: What is the value of `column_index` and `control_index` ?

Comment: 3 and 0   respectivily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

//Code

```
if ((e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit |
DataControlRowState.Alternate)) || (e.Row.RowState ==
DataControlRowState.Edit))
{
/* Edit Mode Code Here (DataControlRowState.Edit) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way too

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
         // you code logic
    }
  }
}
```